# adb and multiple device simultaneously

Tags: android, testing, adb

I am automating some test on android devices.
I am using Jenkins in order to run the tests (via jobs)
each job runs with a 95% success rate when only 1 device is connected to the machine
but when I plug 2 android devices or more, it seems adb has some trouble and I get a 5% success rate.

is it ok to run multiple instances of adb command?

here is the command I run for each job:

```
adb -s DEVICESERIAL shell am force-stop com.myapp.test 
adb -s DEVICESERIAL shell am force-stop com.myapp
adb -s DEVICESERIAL uninstall com.myapp adb -s DEVICESERIAL uninstall com.myapp.test
adb -s DEVICESERIAL install -r com.myapp adb -s DEVICESERIAL install -r com.myapp.test
adb -s DEVICESERIAL shell am instrument -w TESTNAME/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
adb -s DEVICESERIAL logcat -d -v time
```

all command run with success but when the test starts and when I have multiple devices connected i get errors like for example:

```
- Unable to find instrumentation target package
- INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
- Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]
```

at first I thought the test apk was not installed correctly, but when trying manually after the failure, it worked fine (so the test file is installed)

again. Using 1 device only, everything is stable.

Is there something special to do in order to install and run the test on different devices simultaneously?

note that I have tried different usb ports, different cables etc...

thanks

Comment: An interesting test might be what happens if you have two devices connected (so that the serial number MUST be specified) but are only trying to test one device.

Comment: `adb` does not have any inherent problems with multiple devices. in our environment we run tests on dozens of devices connected to the same system at the same time without any issues.

Comment: @CHris if I plug several devices but run only 1 test on 1 device at the time (using -s deviceserial) it works fine. I don't have any INSTRUMENTATION errors

Comment: @Alex are you running multiple tests on multiple devices at the same time? or 1 test at a time? I am interested to know what your configuration is. Are you using Jenkins to run jobs or did you implement your own build integration? are you using Linux/ or windows? etc...

Comment: @Franck, we are running multiple tests on multiple devices at the same time - otherwise I would not bring it up. We do use Jenkins and linux.

Comment: @AlexP. Maybe I should blame windows then? also... are you connecting to the device using the usb cables or over tcp?